# How to load a function after the Script Manager?

Tags: c#, javascript, .net

On code behind I have this code:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "FetchFacebook", "FetchFeeds('facebook');", true);
```

and inside the javascript function `FetchFeeds()` I do a call to a WebServer. The JS reference to it it's on the `ScriptManager`, which is registered on the page after the code behind.

So when I call `FetchFeeds` there isn't yet the webservice reference.

How can I choose when to call `FetchFeeds()` from codebehind?

Comment: Not sure how to force the order, but some workarounds are: If you're using jQuery you can wrap your call in a $(document).ready(function() { FetchFeeds('facebook'); }); call to Ensure it's only called when the whole document (and all ScriptManager stuff) is loaded. Otherwise maybe wrap it in a setTimeout() call (less nice) or instead of adding it by ScriptManager add the script-block to a new literal control which you add to the end of the page control collection.

Comment: I could use `$(document).ready(function()`, but if I need to call it 20 times with `ScriptManager` I have 20 times the .ready :(

Comment: Have you tried using `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript` instead?